# Как ввести URL адрес?

Tags: html, javascript

Никак не могу разобраться, как сделать так, что бы, например, высвечивалась надпись: ВВЕДИТЕ ВАШ URL. Например, вводим http://XXXX.xx, жмем на кнопочку ВВЕДИТЕ и данный сайт по этому URL открывается в этой странице в новом фрейме?

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function goUrl(){
var url=document.forms.myForm.elements.usUrl.value;
window.location = url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="usUrl"  value="http://">
<button name="go" onClick="goUrl()">Перейти</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Leshij_2005- Не получается ничего!!!! Скопировал все что ты тут написал, вставил на сайт и НИЧЕГО!!!! Спасибо дружище, может быть тебе более наглядно будет понять что я хочу посетив этот сайт? http://graffitistudio.ru/ Ссылка-Увеличение просмотров!!! Просто вручную вводишь http:/xxx.zz и на этой же страничке в новом фрейме (скажем 100х100) отображается сайт с адресом http:/xxx.zz. Сама страничка обновляется автоматически с интервалом скажем 45 сек. Эдакая накрутка показов сайта для поднятия рейтинга!

Comment: Ммм... Ну как бы, что я написал, у меня работает, ввожу адрес, нажимаю перейти и в этом же окне открывается страничка с адресом, который я ввел... Пробовал адреса с инета и норм все)

Comment: Прикольно!!! Вот адрес сайта, где я тестирую. http://runway.cc.ua

Comment: Пробывал на narod.ru - тоже самое, не получается. Никуда не переносит после ввода URL

Comment: Не знаю что с Narod,ом, но скрипт работает;)

Comment: Может вручную вводить коды?!

Comment: Укажи страничку, где ты тестировал этот скрипт!

Comment: Я на своем компе) На localhost)) Ну и на сайте который ты указал) Все норм работает)

Comment: Может что то в браузере у меня не так?!!!

Comment: Не ну как бы на сайте твоем (http://runway.cc.ua) работает скрипт, все норм. Мож прост че то в Narod еще надо,хотя я даже не представляю что... Ну можно конечно в браузере посмотреть, включена ли поддержка JavaScript, хотя вряд ли она будет отключена...

Comment: Этот скрипт будет работать только в IE, а почему пока не разобрался. Ищу ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function goUrl(){
var url=document.forms.myForm.elements.usUrl.value;
window.location = url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="usUrl"  value="http://">
//<button name="go" onClick="goUrl()">Перейти</button> когда это меняю на это, то все работает <input type="button" name="go" onClick="goUrl()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Мой скрипт :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script  type="text/javascript">
   function newLocation()
       {
         var ur=document.getElementById('usUrl');
         window.location.href= ur.value;
       }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="usUrl"  value="http://"/>
    <input type = "button" value ="Перейти"onClick="newLocation()"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Пример: [link text](http://php2weeks.hut2.ru/proverka.html)

Comment: Ок) Эт окончательное решение;)

Answer (score 1):

Во фрейме - вот:

```
<input type="text" id="from_here" value="http://hashcode.ru/" /> <input type="button" value="go!" onclick="return openUrlInFrame();"><br />
<iframe id="go_here"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openUrlInFrame() {
  document.getElementById('go_here').src=document.getElementById('from_here').value;
  return false;
  }
</script>
```

Как стили фрейму прописать, думаю, вы знаете)

Answer (score 0):

window.location = prompt('Введите Ваш URL: ');